# Copy latest version file from a folder to another

Tags: command-line, batch

I have to copy the latest version of file from a folder to another folder.

For example:

I have a folder with many files, and each file has more than one version in the same folder **file1-a** and **file1-b**

I need copy only the version **file1-b** (latest version) and don't get the others

I have made this batch file:

```
@echo off
set src_folder=\\ServerName\internal\file
set dst_folder=c:\Users\username\Desktop\extract-file
set file_list=c:\Users\username\Desktop\file-list.txt

if not exist "%dst_folder%" mkdir "%dst_folder%"

for /f "delims=" %%f in (%file_list%) do (
xcopy "%src_folder%\%%f**.jpg" "%dst_folder%\"
)
```

In `file-list.txt` I write the name of the file to move without its version.... File1  File2  File3 etc..

With this batch I can copy files from a folder to another, but all files and all versions

How can i copy the latest version?

For example copy only the **file1-b** instead of **file1-a** + **file1-b**

Comment: What do you have in your `file-list.txt` file? do you have the full path with drive, folder and extension?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry, in the `file-list.txt` I write the names of the files to move to another folder. File1 File2 File3 ........... I write the name of the file to move without its version

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it could been done, in programming there are always several ways to do the same thing....

```
@echo off
set src_folder=%userprofile%\desktop\Source
set dst_folder=%userprofile%\desktop\Destiny
set file_list=%userprofile%\desktop\file-list.txt

if not exist "%dst_folder%" mkdir "%dst_folder%"

pushd "%src_folder%"
for /f "delims=" %%f in (%file_list%) do Call :DoCopy "%%f"

exit

:DoCopy
for /f "delims=" %%g in ('dir /b /o-n "%~1"*') do (
                                                   xcopy /f /y /h "%%g" "%dst_folder%\"
                                                   goto :EOF
                                                  )
goto :EOF
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, it's perfect!! Thank you very much!!!